# MySQL performance of trigger when many rows are affected

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a question on MySQL triggers which I hope someone might be able to help with.  As part of our platform, we have a table (accounting), which grows rapidly. We also have an archived version of the table which unneeded rows from accounting are copied into (by a trigger).  This archived table has an extra column (deleted) which states whether that particular row was deleted from accounting.

Now, I want to have a 2nd script run, which will remove the archived records from accounting (I'm thinking around a 1000 at a time, run every 30 seconds to a minute) and, need to consider two scenarios:

1 - have a delete trigger on accounting, that sets the deleted column in the archive table to true where the id matches.

2 - Don't have a trigger but, create a temporary table of ID's that need to be deleted, delete the rows from accounting where the ID's match, set the deleted column of the archive table to true where the ID's match, then drop the temporary table.

I am leaning towards the 2nd option, as I'm aware that triggers in MySQL are based on each row, so there could be up to 1000 update statements running every time the script executes.  However, I'm wondering if the performance between the two scenarios actually would be significantly different?

Hope this makes sense.

Kind Regards

Daryl

Comment: "When" do you want to delete/archive a row?  Perhaps after N days?  What version of MySQL are you running?  How many `INSERTs/UPDATEs` per second are happening on this table?  (If too many, you will definitely need a different scheme.)